# Where to find an image-gallery builder

Tags: html, image-gallery

I am searching for a program that builds image galleries just as on this website http://jouwbusinessclub.nl/page.php?31

The problem is that simpleviewer (the one that is used here) is to limited because it can not create categories.

Does anyone knows a good program for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TinyWebGallery](http://www.tinywebgallery.com/de/main.php)

Comment: I think it's great, but isn't there a simpeler solution, just as simpleviewer?